# Question in proof of Multipilcation of matrices in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

While self studying linear Algebra from Hoffman Kunze I have a question in proof of a theorem whose image I am adding :

[image]

This theorem would be useful->

[image]

( Due to some glitch both images automatically appeared at last not here).

> Question:How in proof authors introduced 2nd variable s without it being in subscript $\sum_{s} B_{rj} C_{rj} $  ?

I tried by putting s as follows :

$\sum_{r} A_{ir}\sum_{s} B_{rjs} C_{srj} $  but this doesn't proves the RHS in last line as $\sum_{s} \sum_{r} A_{ir} B_{rjs} C_{srj} $ = $\sum_{s} (AB)_{iks} C_{srj} $= But in next step I don't know how to solve to get what is to be proved as subscript is iks and srj.

So, kindly tell what mistake I am making.

Comment: I am guessing your confusion arises as you are not sure how the second line is introduced. This is just the definition of $(r,j)$th entry of $BC$. Please ignore me if I misunderstood you.  Also your attempt doesnt make sense since $B_{rjs}$ is not defined

Comment: What do you mean by $B_{rjs}$?

Comment: I don't see any occurrence of $\sum_{s} B_{rj} C_{rj} $. What are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to understand what exactly has confused you and how you decided that $A,B$ should have three subscripts. However, since it is clear that your issue has something to do with summation notation, perhaps it would be useful to look at a concrete example.

Let's consider the specific case where $A,B,C$ are each of size $3 \times 3$. Now, the confusing part of the proof is
$$
[A(BC)]_{ij} = \sum_rA_{ir} (BC)_{rj} = \sum_r A_{ir}\sum_s B_{rs}C_{sj}.
$$
First of all, let's understand the definition of matrix multiplication.  We have
$$
(AB)_{ij} = \sum_{r} A_{ir}B_{rj} = A_{i1}B_{1j} + A_{i2}B_{2j} + A_{i3}B_{3j}.
$$
With that, we can write
$$
[A(BC)]_{ij} = A_{i1}(BC)_{1j} + A_{i2}(BC)_{2j} + A_{i3}(BC)_{3j}\\
= A_{i1}(B_{11}C_{1j} + B_{12}C_{2j} + B_{13}C_{3j})\qquad \\
\qquad + A_{i2}(B_{21}C_{1j} + B_{22}C_{2j} + B_{23}C_{3j})\\
\qquad + A_{i3}(B_{31}C_{1j} + B_{32}C_{2j} + B_{33}C_{3j}).
$$
Can you see that the 3-line sum above is the same thing as
$$
\sum_{r=1}^3 A_{ir}\left(\sum_{s=1}^3 B_{rs}C_{sj}\right)?
$$

Comment: there is a typo in a line after the  line "With that, we can write"?

Comment: @user795826 Fixed. In any case, does that make sense now?

Answer (score 1):

Let us redo the computation in a different order.

$$(BC)_{sj}=\sum_rB_{sr}C_{rj}$$

and

$$(A(BC))_{ij}=\sum_s A_{is}(BC)_{sj}=\sum_s A_{is}\left(\sum_rB_{sr}C_{rj}\right)=\sum_s\sum_rA_{is}B_{sr}C_{rj}.$$

On the other hand,

$$(AB)_{ir}=\sum_s A_{is}B_{sr}$$

and

$$((AB)C)_{ij}=\sum_r(AB)_{ir}C_{rj}=\sum_r\left(\sum_s A_{is}B_{sr}\right)C_{rj}=\sum_r\sum_s A_{is}B_{sr}C_{rj}.$$